# Best network topology for a large business and a small one

Tags: design

I would like to know which could be a more reliable topology for both as well as the cost of implementing it or an estimated if possible.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you find this a great community to contribute to and learn from. Your question is asking for opinions and we are unable to provide a *correct* answer. Please edit your question and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Networks are typically segregated between access and core/distribution devices.  Access switches that operate together as a single logical switch are dual homed (2 uplinks or more) to the core/distribution pair of networking devices, which themselves operate as a single logical device.  This design allows for no interruption of network service in case of a single uplink or single switch outage, with the exception of the devices plugged in to an access switch that might fail.  Servers are typically dual homed to a pair of access switches themselves as well.

This is the best design no matter the size.  Basically you want everything redundant - redundant networking devices, redundant uplinks between networking devices, and even redundant applications/servers.

Comment: Thank you! Ron Royston. Great response! I'm learning more about networks so sometimes i have some doubts.